# How to "cut" the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$ to remove the singularity in $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, singularity

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$. I am looking for a proper cut of $f$ which returns a function which removes the singularity in $0$ and remains continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

Could someone please suggest me something?

I was thinking about something like a function which is equal to $f$ outside the ball $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$, $\varepsilon>0$, but I don't know how to assume it inside the ball.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do anything you want inside the ball. For example connect the two ends with a straight line.

Comment: what properties do you want the resulting function to have besides having no singularity? Just continuity still leaves you with a lot of options, like a connecting line like kolja suggests

Comment: @Kolja, what it would be the right analytical expression of that?

Comment: $$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & |x|>\epsilon \\ -\frac{1}{\epsilon^3} + \frac{x+\epsilon}{\epsilon^4}& \text{else}\end{cases} $$

Comment: @FelixB. thank you for your comment. But why you choose exactly $-\frac{1}{\varepsilon^3}$ and $\frac{2}{\varepsilon^3}$ for the straight line?

Comment: @C.Bishop because you need to make sure that you have continuity at the borders $x=\pm\epsilon$

Comment: Notice that $\frac{-1}{\varepsilon^3} + \frac{x+\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^4} = x\frac{1}{\varepsilon^4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we want to change the function only in $\{|x| \leq \varepsilon\}$, and to it in the simplest way possible -- connect the end points with a line. The line would have to pass through two end points which are
$$
(x_0,y_0) = \left(\varepsilon, \tfrac{1}{\varepsilon^3}\right) \quad \text{ and }\quad (x_1,y_1) = \left(-\varepsilon, \tfrac{-1}{\varepsilon^3}\right)
$$

The line passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ is $y=x\cdot \frac{1}{\varepsilon^4}$. Therefore the function is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^3} &\text{if $|x|\geq \varepsilon$}, \\
x \frac{1}{\varepsilon^4} &\text{ if $|x| < \varepsilon$}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Kolja, but for $\varepsilon$ very small, say $\varepsilon\to 0$, we have a singularity in $x \frac{1}{\varepsilon^4}$, isn't it?

Comment: For $\varepsilon \to 0$ the function tends to $\frac{1}{x^3}$. This is expected behaviour. You only wanted a function that is equal to $\frac{1}{x^3}$ at $|x|\geq \varepsilon$ and is continuous. The function $f$ satisfies those properties for any $ \varepsilon>0$. In other words for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is ONE such function. There is no single function for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: NB. For very small $\varepsilon$ there is NO singularity. There are no singularities for any $\varepsilon>0$.